# TImageList - images do not look as they should

Tags: delphi, png, timagelist

I have just noticed that TImageList in delphi (I have xe2 and xe8) draws PNG images wrong. At the screenshot you can see that reflection and edges look different (on the left is a TImage that shows my PNG correctly). ColorDepth is cd32Bit. I tried different PNGs with same result. Please advise a solution.

[image: imagelist]

Comment: What are the rest of the properties of the image list? Does it draw correctly at runtime? Which version of Delphi? Can you share the PNG file?

Comment: And what we see here is a design time window. Do you really have a *run-time* issue?

Comment: Also keep in mind that `TImageList` is a wrapper for a Win32 `IMAGELIST` control that only supports BMP and ICO images.  Recent versions of Delphi allow you to add PNGs to `TImageList` at design-time, but they get converted to BMP when stored. `TImage` does not do that. What you really need is a PNG-enabled ImageList, such as `TPngImageList` from the [PngComponents](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/26127) suite. If you are going to use a standard `TImageList`, at least make sure that its `DrawingStyle` is `dsTransparent` and its `ColorDepth` is `cd32Bit`.

Comment: Properties of ImageList are cd32Bit and dsTransparent (rest of them are default). When I assign images from ImageList to, let's say, ToolBar I still have the issue (at runtime as well). Thanks Remy, I'll take a look at TPngImageList!

Comment: PNG files:   http://i.imgur.com/kjrU5Vr.png  http://i.imgur.com/n2eujCB.png